# Bootstrap toggle modal show on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a few links

```
<a  class="linkd"
   data-target="#download-confirm-modal"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-link="link-id">Download</a>
```

and I want after clicking button in the modal disable showing modals for all ".linkd"-class when clicked. But after another action I want to restore that behaviour. I've tried to remove data-attributes

```
$(".linkd").removeData("target");
$(".linkd").removeData("toggle");
```

but that doesn't work. I found solution

```
$(document).off('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]');
```

but I don't know how to enable it again.
What is the correct way to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I would have used the `<button>` element instead of an `<a>` as it's not really a link, right? But some JS triggering element. The `<button>` element has got the `disabled` attribute which can be set to all other buttons under your conditions